# Stream api filter

Tags: java, java-stream

Всем привет!) Столкнулась с проблемой... Моя небольшая голова все никак не может придумать, как можно отфильтровать один стрим одного типа по другому другого типа. Если конкретнее, то - я пишу симулятор лифта, один Stream у меня Integer, второй Passenger. `Stream<Integer>` представляет из себя последовательность заявок. Мне нужно отфильтровать этот стрим так, чтобы к пассажирам, которые уже вошли в кабину(boolean isEntered), лифт не ехал, но если уж он их забрал, то необходимо доехать до этажа конечной остановки. Тоесть, from откинуть, а to оставить. Что-то типа такого:

```
stations = stations.stream().filter(station -> passengers.stream().flatMap(p -> Stream.of((if !p.isEtered)p.getDepature, (and required)p.getDestination)));
```

Как-то так. Криво конечно, но совсем не знаю как это можно провернуть. Помогите, пожалуйста :3

Comment: Не проще ли заявки хранить в самом пассажире? Ведь признак того, что пассажир в кабине вы именно там храните. Так у вас останется один стрим с пассажирами. Т.о., берем стрим с пассажирами, смотри кто вошел и куда едет, сортируем, если надо, последовательно всех везем на нужный этаж итд...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, вам нужно что-то такое

```
Set<Integer> stops = Stream.concat(
    passengers.stream().filter(x -> !x.isEntered()).map(Passenger::getDeparture),
    passengers.stream().map(Passenger::getDestination)
).collect(Collectors.toSet());

Stream<Integer> result = stations.stream().filter(stops::contains);
```

Comment: То что нужно!) Спасибо!)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю что-нибудь такое. Накидал так как представил по вашему разъяснению задачу.

```
class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> stations = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    App outer = new App();
    List<Passenger> passengers = new ArrayList<>();

    passengers.add(outer.new Passenger(1));
    passengers.add(outer.new Passenger(2));
    passengers.add(outer.new Passenger(3));
    passengers.add(outer.new Passenger(4));

    System.out.println(passengers);

    List<Integer> newStations =
        stations.stream()
            .filter(
                station ->
                    passengers.stream().anyMatch(p -> !p.isEntered() && p.departure == station))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(newStations);
  }

  public class Passenger {
    private Integer number;
    private Integer departure;
    private Integer destination;
    private Boolean entered;

    public Passenger(Integer number) {
      this.departure = (int) (Math.random() * 5) + 1;
      this.destination = (int) (Math.random() * 5) + 1;
      this.entered = false;
      this.number = number;
    }

    public Integer getDepature() {
      return this.departure;
    }

    public Integer getDestination() {
      return this.destination;
    }

    public Boolean isEntered() {
      return entered;
    }

    public void setEntered(Boolean entered) {
      this.entered = entered;
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
      return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
      this.number = number;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return "number = "
          + this.number
          + " departure = "
          + this.departure
          + " destination = "
          + this.destination
          + " entered = "
          + this.entered;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Супер!! Большое спасибо!)